# matter.js applyForce doesn't work inside of collision event handler

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I wrote some code that let's something happen after a collision between two objects in matter.js got detected. I wanted to let the `rectangle` object move by using

```
Matter.Body.applyForce(rectangle, rectangle.position, {x: 0.5, y: -0.5});
```

which worked like this but didn't work like the following:

```
Matter.Events.on(engine, "beforeUpdate", function() {
        Matter.Detector.canCollide(rectangle.collisionFilter,
                                   circleOfDeath.collisionFilter,
                                   collisionEventHandler);
    });

var collisionEventHandler = Matter.Events.on(
    engine,
    "collisionStart",
    function (event) {
        var pairs = event.pairs;
        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i];
            if (
                (pair.bodyA === rectangle && pair.bodyB === slide) ||
                (pair.bodyA === slide && pair.bodyB === rectangle)
            ) {
                rectangle.render.fillStyle = "blue";
                Matter.Body.applyForce(rectangle, rectangle.position, {x: 0.5, y: -0.5});
            }
        }
    }
);

// Add the collision event handler to the engine

Matter.Events.on(engine, "beforeUpdate", function() {
    Matter.Detector.canCollide(slide.collisionFilter, rectangle.collisionFilter, collisionEventHandler);
});
```

I was able to change the rectangle's fillStyle to blue, but the `applyForce` didn't work at all.

I'd be very happy if someone is able to help me!